# Why does the execution of these functions break out of this while loop?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, ffmpeg, read

The following script is meant to trim all media files in the current working directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

trimmer() {
  of=$(echo "${if}"|sed -E "s/(\.)([avimp4kvweb]{3,3}$)/\1trimmed\.\2/")
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -ss "${b}" -to "${ddecreased}" -i "${if}" -c copy "${of}"
  echo "Success. Exiting .."
}

get_ddecreased() {
  duration="$(ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries format=duration -hide_banner "${if}"|grep duration|sed -E s/duration=\([0-9]*\)\..*$/\\1/)"
  echo ${duration} 
  ddecreased="$(echo "${duration} - ${trimming}"|bc -l)"
  echo ${ddecreased} 
}

rm_source() {
  echo -e "Remove ${if}?[Y/n]?"
  read ch
  if [[ "${ch}" == 'y' ]]; then
    rm "${if}"
  fi 
}


echo "How much of the beginning would you like to trim?"
read b
echo "How much of the end would you like to trim?"
read trimming

ls *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.vob >list_of_files

echo "Prompt before removing the source[Y/n]?"
read ch
while IFS="" read -r if || [[ -n "${if}" ]]; do
  if [[ "${ch}" == 'y' ]]; then
    get_ddecreased  && trimmer && rm_source
  elif [[ "${ch}" == 'n' ]]; then
    get_ddecreased && trimmer && rm "${if}"
  fi
  echo $if
done <list_of_files

echo -e "Removing list_of_files."
rm list_of_files
```

If the user selected `y` when asked `Prompt before removing the source[Y/n]` and  `trimmer` has finished trimming the first file `rm_source` is meant to prompt the user and **wait for their input** before removing the source file. This does not work as
the script does not wait for the input and proceeds straight away to `echo -e "Removing list_of_files."` much like there was no while loop at all.
Neither does the while loop get executed when the user selected `n` when asked `Prompt before removing the source[Y/n]` - the script proceeds straight away to `echo -e "Removing list_of_files."` instead of iterating through all the files listed in `list_of_files`. Why so?
Yet when I comment out all these lines

```
if [[ "${ch}" == 'y' ]]; then
    get_ddecreased  && trimmer && rm_source
  elif [[ "${ch}" == 'n' ]]; then
    get_ddecreased && trimmer && rm "${if}"
  fi
```

within the while loop all the lines of `list_of_files` get printed to the screen.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Think about where input is coming from for the `read` call in your function. Hint: Standard input is no longer connected to a terminal there.

Comment: Sidebar - using `ls` in scripting is a bad idea; just put that in a for loop or use `find`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is essentially doing the following:

```bash
foo () {
    read variable
}

while read something; do
    foo
done <input-file
```

The intention is to have the `read` in `foo` read something from the terminal, however, it is being called in a context where the standard input stream is redirected from some file.

This means that the `read` in `foo` will read from the input stream coming from the input file, not from the terminal at all.

You may circumvent this by making the loop read from a another file descriptor than standard input:

```bash
foo () {
    read variable
}

while read something <&3; do
    foo
done 3<input-file
```

Here, the `read` in the loop reads from file descriptor 3, which is being connected to the input file after the `done` keyword.  This leaves the `read` in the `foo` function free to use the original standard input stream.

In the `bash` shell, rather than using a hard-coded value for the extra filedescriptor, you can have the shell allocate the descriptor in a shell variable:

```bash
foo () {
    read variable
}

while read something <&"$fd"; do
    foo
done {fd}<input-file
```

This would likely set `$fd` to an integer like 10 or higher. The exact value is unimportant.

---

In your current code in the question, you may also fix your issue by avoiding creating and reading from the list of files, and instead use the file globs directly:

```bash
for filename in *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.vob; do
    if [ ! -e "$filename" ]; then
        # skip non-existing names
        continue
    fi

    # use "$filename" here
    # ... and call your rm_source function
done
```

This avoids redirections all-together.  This also allows your code to handle the odd file with newline characters in its name.

The `if` statement in the loop, which tests for the existence of the named file, is necessary as the shell will, by default, retain the globbing pattern if there are no matching names for that pattern.  You may get rid of the `if` statement in the `bash` shell by setting the `nullglob` [shell option using](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html) `shopt -s nullglob`.  Setting this option would make the `bash` shell remove non-matching globs completely.

Note too that this is not the same as in your code if any name matching the globbing patterns is a *directory*.  If you have a directory called e.g. `mydir.mp3`, then `ls` would list the *contents* of that directory.  Also, if a filename matching the patterns starts with a dash, the code using `ls` would likely mistake that name for a set of options.

Comment: Is `while IFS="" read l <&7; ` equivalent to `while IFS="" read -u 7 -r l;`?  I've been using the latter in the past but it occasionally lead to unpredictable results (sometimes there was something more in this descriptor than what I intended to redirect) and so I stopped using today. But the cure turned out to be event was that the original issue...

Comment: @JohnSmith The two commands in your comment are equivalent in the `bash` shell, yes.

Comment: @JohnSmith Since you have modified the code in the question in such a way that the file list file is _only used for the loop_, you may get rid of it completely, which also solves your issue.  See updated answer.

Comment: @JohnSmith, those aren't the same as the second one has the `-r` option to `read` (keep backslashes as-is), and the first one doesn't. Usually you want `read -r`. As for `-u 7` vs. `<&7`, -u` might be slightly better in terms of performance, since there's less file descriptor juggling involved. Basically, with `-u 7` the shell just reads directly from fd 7, but with `<&7` it needs to duplicate fd 7 to fd 0 and then read from there (saving the original fd 0 for the while).

Comment: `for filename in *.avi *.mkv *.mp4 *.vob` has the caveat that any unmatching globs would appear as-is by default, so that may need checking in the loop or just using `shopt -s nullglob`. (`ls` would print error messages for them but nothing to stdout)

Comment: @ilkkachu So it is, I will modify my answer. I also missed the lack of `-r` in the user's comment as I was concentrating on the use of the descriptors. Thanks for picking up on that.

Comment: @ilkkachu There are also other issues that may cause a difference in behaviour: When a _directory_ matches the filename globs, and when a name starts with a dash.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yes, that's true, and using the glob directly is better for both of those (not to mention filenames with newlines, ngh). I only meant to point out the one quirk that moving from `ls` to a direct glob might bring. Not that it's even a bad one, they'll just get an error message from `rm` if it gets passed a nonexisting filename.